# can sonar qube be executed only certain files on GIT repository

Tags: sonarqube

I tried to trigger Jenkins job and execute sonar qube analysis through PR push on GIT repository . My repository is pretty large and i have been wondering if execution of sonar qube could be done just with respect to modified files ( as in every time you make changes to certain file ) . Instead of letting whole of jenkins job to run every time a PR is made to GIT. ??

Answer (score 1):

> can sonar qube be executed only certain files on GIT repository

This is basically what the [Sonar GitHub Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) does,
and it seems it would be suitable for your purpose.

It analyzes changes in pull requests without pushing analyses to SonarQube. Any issues that are found in the modified parts of the code are published as comments on the pull request.